(VSCODE on WSL) The import cannot be solved
I'm encountering an issue with vscode where it's unable to resolve imports for some generated libraries located under target/generated-sources/src. Despite reading numerous guides and attempting various solutions such as modifying the pom file, cleaning the Java workspace, and more, nothing seems to be working. Interestingly, IntelliJ handles this properly, but unfortunately, I'm stuck with this problem on vscode. I've even tried disabling and re-enabling all extensions, but to no avail.
My vscode version is 1.88.1.
Any suggestions?

Any suggestions? - try building it from the command line, you may see more.

I'm able to compile and run from terminal, don't understand why.
@BIBOO vscode is on windows and both ubuntu wsl

I just solved by myself, just opening Classpath configuration using the path of the generated classes



For Maven project, you can add a dependency by clicking the + icon next to Maven Dependencies node in project view.


https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_dependency-management

That works when you use official maven repository, not custom. Anyway I just solved by myself
